# resizing plot output causes raster and points to become misaligned

Tags: r, gis

If I use plot() to draw a GIS raster image, then use points() to add some points on the image:  E.g. the following code

```
in_rast_str <- "PET_eclp.tif"
in_rast <- raster(in_rast_str)
selected_cells <- choose_points(in_rast_str,10,30)
plot(in_rast)
points(selected_cells[,1],selected_cells[,2])
```

The initial output renders correctly. However, if I then resize the plot either in the export window, or in the zoom window of RStudio, the points and the underlying raster shift relative to each other and become misaligned.

Is this a problem with RStudio or with R?
I'm guessing that this could be a bug rather than that I am doing something obviously wrong.

**Update...**

Here are some examples:
[image: original plot]

and the same plot, but resized

[image]

Comment: I wonder if aspect ratio has anything to do with this?

Comment: Thanks Roman. I think you are on the right tracks that it is related to aspect ratio.  But I don't think that is the whole story. I think it is something to do with the raster being rescaled, but the points being plotted still at the original scale.  In the examples pictures I added to the post, you can see that not only the positions of the points change but also their size.  So it looks like a scaling issue rather than just an aspect ratio one.

Comment: I thought there's something awfully familiar about this. I asked the same question a while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977419/ploting-artefact-with-points-over-raster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That issue with `raster` has been annoying me for years.

This doesn't exactly answer your question, but `rasterVis` provides a very pleasing (to me, anyway) workaround.

```
library(rasterVis)
r <- raster(matrix(runif(100), 10))  
xy <- xyFromCell(r, which(values(r) > 0.9))

levelplot(r, margin=FALSE) + layer(sp.points(xy, pch=20, cex=2, col=1))
```

[image]

Resize and zoom around as much as you like - the points will stick to the correct cells.

Comment: @mdsumner has drilled down the problem and it's points() that's causing hot blood. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5985523/322912

Comment: @Roman - thanks, just saw the post you linked. Good to know! (But I'll stick with `rasterVis` in most cases!)